Polars Python: Filter list column using a boolean list column, but keeping list size
I would like to get elements from a list dtype column using another boolean list column and keeping the original size of the list (as oppose to this solution).
Starting from this dataframe:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'identity_vector': [[True, False], [False, True]],
    'string_vector': [['name1', 'name2'], ['name3', 'name4']]
})

shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ identity_vector ┆ string_vector      │
│ ---             ┆ ---                │
│ list[bool]      ┆ list[str]          │
╞═════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ [true, false]   ┆ ["name1", "name2"] │
│ [false, true]   ┆ ["name3", "name4"] │
└─────────────────┴────────────────────┘

The objective is to get this output:
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────────────┬────────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ identity_vector ┆ string_vector      ┆ filtered_strings │
│ ---             ┆ ---                ┆ ---              │
│ list[bool]      ┆ list[str]          ┆ list[str]        │
╞═════════════════╪════════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ [true, false]   ┆ ["name1", "name2"] ┆ ["name1", null]  │
│ [false, true]   ┆ ["name3", "name4"] ┆ [null, "name4"]  │
└─────────────────┴────────────────────┴──────────────────┘


Which I can get using the block of code below and map_elements, but the solution is sub-optimal for performance reasons:
df.with_columns(
    filtered_strings=pl.struct(["string_vector", "identity_vector"]).map_elements(
        lambda row: [s if keep else None for s, keep in zip(row["string_vector"], row["identity_vector"])]
    )
)


Do you have any suggestion on how to improve the performance of this process?

It may be worth asking if this would be considered as an API addition? I modified the plugin example as a test: https://marcogorelli.github.io/polars-plugins-tutorial/lists_in_lists_out/ (to give the index of true values and null for false) - it was ~10x faster than list.eval. Passing to list.gather was still expensive, but I imagine a proper native implementation could bypass that.

Thanks! I sadly cannot install Rust in my machine due to limitations at org level, but I will open the request!

Kind of standard pl.Expr.explode() / calculate / pl.Expr.implode() route:
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.col.identity_vector.explode()
    ).then(
        pl.col.string_vector.explode()
    ).otherwise(None)
    .implode()
    .over(pl.int_range(pl.len()))
    .alias("filtered_strings")
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────────────┬────────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ identity_vector ┆ string_vector      ┆ filtered_strings │
│ ---             ┆ ---                ┆ ---              │
│ list[bool]      ┆ list[str]          ┆ list[str]        │
╞═════════════════╪════════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ [true, false]   ┆ ["name1", "name2"] ┆ ["name1", null]  │
│ [false, true]   ┆ ["name3", "name4"] ┆ [null, "name4"]  │
└─────────────────┴────────────────────┴──────────────────┘

There're also other possible approaches, for example using pl.Expr.list.eval() and pl.Expr.list.gather()
df.with_columns(
    pl.col.string_vector.list.gather(
        pl.col.identity_vector.list.eval(
            pl.when(pl.element()).then(pl.int_range(pl.len()))
        )
    ).alias("filtered_strings")
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────────────┬────────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ identity_vector ┆ string_vector      ┆ filtered_strings │
│ ---             ┆ ---                ┆ ---              │
│ list[bool]      ┆ list[str]          ┆ list[str]        │
╞═════════════════╪════════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ [true, false]   ┆ ["name1", "name2"] ┆ ["name1", null]  │
│ [false, true]   ┆ ["name3", "name4"] ┆ [null, "name4"]  │
└─────────────────┴────────────────────┴──────────────────┘

Or, if you know length of your lists or it's relatively small, you can create columns for each list index and then use pl.Expr.list.get() and pl.concat_list().
l = 2
df.with_columns(
    filtered_strings = pl.concat_list(
        pl.when(
            pl.col.identity_vector.list.get(i)
        ).then(
            pl.col.string_vector.list.get(i)
        )
        for i in range(2)
    )
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────────────┬────────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ identity_vector ┆ string_vector      ┆ filtered_strings │
│ ---             ┆ ---                ┆ ---              │
│ list[bool]      ┆ list[str]          ┆ list[str]        │
╞═════════════════╪════════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ [true, false]   ┆ ["name1", "name2"] ┆ ["name1", null]  │
│ [false, true]   ┆ ["name3", "name4"] ┆ [null, "name4"]  │
└─────────────────┴────────────────────┴──────────────────┘

All solutions use pl.when() to set value to null when condition is not met.
